# Redirecting /media/* to /project/media/* and everything else to /dispatch.php

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following rewrite rules:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /

  # Route requests to /media/* to /projects/media/*
  RewriteRule ^media/.* - [NC,L]

  # Route all URLs to dispatch.php.
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dispatch.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

This redirects everything to dispatch.php, unless the URL is `example.com/media/*` in which case it will look for the requested file in `./media/`. I would like the URL `/media/*` to be rewritten to look in `project/media/*`.

Using the rewrite rule `RewriteRule ^media/.* project/media [NC,L]` results in everything going to dispatch.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012083/rewrite-rules-showing-in-location-bar-of-browser).

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to capture the path and append it. Such as:

```
RewriteRule ^media/(.*)$ project/media/$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: I've already tried this and it results in everything being rewritten to dispatch.php

Answer (score 0):

Try these rules:

```
RewriteRule ^media/.* project/$0 [NC,L]
RewriteRule !^project/ dispatch.php [L]
```

Comment: This rule doesn't work. Also I would like to route /media/ to the directory /projects/media.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
# Route requests to /media/* to /projects/media/*
RewriteRule ^media/(.*)$ project/media/$1 [L]
# Route all URLs to dispatch.php.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/project/media/.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ maintenance.php [L]
```

Originally I wanted to use the special `%{IS_SUBREQ}` variable, but I couldn't get it working.