# Rewrite rules showing in location bar of browser

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following rewrite rules:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /

  # Route all URLs to dispatch.php.
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !media/
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dispatch.php [L]

  #Route requests to /media/* to /project/media/*
  RewriteRule ^media/(.*)?$ project/media/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

Everything is rewritten to `dispatch.php` unless the URI starts with `media/` in which case it will rewrite the URI to `project/media/*`. Everything works fine and if I navigate to `example.com/media/css/style.css` the stylesheet it served. If I navigate to `example.com/media/css/` then a 403 Forbidden error is sent. Perfect!

However, If I navigate to `example.com/media/css` (missing the trailing '/') then the URL in the location bar is rewritten to `example.com/project/media/css` and the request is handled by `dispatch.php`. How do I stop this behaviour from happening? I would like it to be handled by `dispatch.php` but without `projects/` being added to the URL.

**Solved:** The problem was due to mod_dir redirecting the URLs that had no trailing slash. This resulted in the location as it appears on disk being used for the redirect which means that the subfolder (project) was appended to the URI. The final .htaccess that I used is as follows:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews -Indexes
Options -Indexes

<IfModule mod_dir.c>
  DirectorySlash Off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /

  #Add trailing slashes
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [R=301,L]

  #Route requests to /media/* to /project/media/*
  RewriteRule ^media(/.*)$ project/media$1 [L]

  # Route all URLs to dispatch.php.
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^media/(.*)
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dispatch.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

The new .htaccess does the same as before as well as:

- Disables mod_dir.
- Adds trailing slashes to the URI
  through the use of a RewriteRule.

Comment: No need to create a new question: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010249/redirecting-media-to-project-media-and-everything-else-to-dispatch-php

Comment: I'll make sure I don't do this again but I thought that the aim was sufficently different to require it's own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could explicitly block those directory urls with other rewrite rules.

Or... You can use DirectorySlash to turn off the redirect.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_dir.html

Comment: Thanks, it took me a while to figure out why you were talking about mod_dir!